# Multiple symptoms, maybe electrical?

Tags: electrical, stall

My high-mileage 2010 Kia Soul (automatic transmission) just came down with a case of "everything's broken all at once". Symptoms include:

- Stalling at idle
- Slow to start after adding gas
- Lurching when downshifting
- Traction control comes on after a few minutes of driving
- Cruise control no longer works

Does anybody know if there's a common cause for all of the above issues? I've replaced the spark plugs and am going to try cleaning the MAF next. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say “all at once” do you literally mean all in the same day.

Comment: Somehow yes, all symptoms started on the same day, although it's been stalling more frequently each time I drive it

Comment: A common cause for multiple electronic failures is low battery voltage. Have you had the battery properly tested?

Comment: What is your definition of high mileage? Over 300k?

Comment: @Jupiter, I haven't had it checked - I'll do that tomorrow

Comment: @SolarMike, just over 200k

Comment: While "shotgun replacement" is frowned upon, I'd try to lend a healthy battery from someone and see if the symptoms get resolved.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I'd do is find an OBD scanner tool and see if it's throwing any codes.
Some things that come to mind however are:

- Vacuum leak from somewhere.
- Throttle position sensor failure (which would explain stalling, lurching, hard starting, cruise not working etc)
- As others have stated, battery or alternator failing

While it doesn't explain the cruise and traction control, the poor engine performance may also be explained by a clogged fuel filter and/or air filter.